# How can I bind a shortcut to execute a shell command in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, keyboard

This is the command I want to execute.

```
rm -rf /tmp/steam*
```

How can I do this and bind it to a key?

Answer (score 1):

In Automator you can build a service. Choose no input in every application. Then add the step Run Shell Script and paste your script.

Save the service. Now you can assign a keyboard shortcut in

System Preferences...Keyboard...Keyboard Shortcuts...Services...General.

Comment: There is no "General"